# Handle Deserialization Error (Dead Letter Queue) in a kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, dead-letter

After some research i found few configuration i can use to handle this.

default.deserialization.exception.handler - from the StreamsConfig

errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name - from the SinkConnector config

I cant seem to find the equivalent valid configuration for a simple consumer

I want to start a simple consumer and have a DLQ handling whether its via just stating the DLQ topic and let kafka produce it ( like in the sink connector) or purely providing my own class that will produce it (like the streams config).

How can i achieve a DLQ with a simple consumer?

EDIT: Another option i figured is simply handling it in my Deserializer class, just catch an exception there and produce it to my DLQ
But it will mean ill need to create a producer in my deserializer class...
Is this the best practice to handle a DLQ from a consumer?